# Java process thread details

Tags: java, threads

I'd like to get the details like name, running time, etc. of threads of a Java process on a production VM, similar to the info that VisualVM shows in the Threads tab. Unfortunately, VisualVM won't run without JDK installed. Is there any light-weight alternative for Windows?
I've already tried the PowerShell command

```
Get-CimInstance win32_thread -filter “handle = ThreadID”
```

It does not show anything useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the info that I needed in 2 steps.

1. Obtained IDs of threads that kept CPU busy using [Performance Monitor](http://developer.voxtron.com/?p=32)
2. Copied jstack and the necessary components from JDK as described [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30095717/456181)

Then I found the details of the threads in the output of jstack using thread IDs from step 1.